# find if list 1 is a sequence of list 2 in haskell

Tags: haskell

im trying to check if a given list is a subsequence of another list:

here are example of lists which gives true:

```
subseq "" "w"
subseq "w" "w"
subseq "ab" "cab"
subseq "cb" "cab"
subseq "aa" "xaxa"
not (subseq "aa" "xax")
not (subseq "ab" "ba")
```

i just come to this but in some cases it gives a wrong result

```
subseq :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
subseq [] [] = True
subseq [] ys = True
subseq xs [] = False
subseq (x:xs) (y:ys) = x == y || subseq xs ( 1 `drop` ys )
```

Comment: there will be `isSubsequenceOf` function available: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:isSubsequenceOf

Answer (score 7):

Two things, one high level and one low level. High level first:

Your recursive case is incorrect. In English, you've written that a nonempty list is a subsequence of another nonempty list if either their first characters match, or if every character except the first in list 1 is a subsequence of every character but the first two in the second list. This is clearly incorrect, since for instance "aaa" is not a subsequence of "abc" even though their first characters match, and "db" is not a subsequence of "cab" even though "b" is a subsequence of "b".

A better approach to that final case is to express it as, in English: "A nonempty list is a subsequence of another nonempty list if either: 1. their first characters match and the remaining characters of list one are a subsequence of the remaining characters of list two, or 2. their first characters *do not* match and list one is a subsequence of all the characters in list two except the first."

Since this looks like homework I'll leave it to you to translate that out into Haskell code.

Low level: the code fragment

```
subseq (x:xs) (y:ys) = x == y || subseq xs ( 1 `drop` ys )
```

doesn't do what you think it does. `ys` is already all the elements in the second list except the first; you don't need to drop any more elements from it. Also, the first case (`subseq [] [] = True`) is unnecessary since it'll be caught by the second case, but that's not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

This does it:

```
import Control.Monad

subseq a b = elem a . filterM (\x-> [True,False]) $ b
```

([thank you SO / sacundim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12713201/849891) for that!).

Taking the advise from jacobm's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13220710/849891), you get

```
subseq [] ys = True
subseq xs [] = False
subseq (x:xs) (y:ys) = x == y && (....) 
                    || x /= y && subseq (....) (....)
```

which is better written with guards,

```
subseq (x:xs) (y:ys) 
             | x == y    = (....) 
             | otherwise = subseq (....) (....)
```

---

The first code is better regarded as *specification*, not code, it is very inefficient. To improve it we can try *fusing* `elem` and `filterM` - which might have been implemented as

```
filterM p xs = liftM concat $ sequence [ do {t<-p x; return [x|t]} | x<-xs]
```

so that

```
elem xs $ filterM (\x-> [True,False]) ys                               ==
elem xs $ map concat $ sequence [ [[y|t] | t<-[True,False]] | y<-ys]   ==
elem xs $ map concat $ sequence [ [[y],[]] | y<-ys]                    ==

not.null $ filter (match [[x]|x<-xs]) $ sequence [ [[y],[]] | y<-ys]
  where
    match [] _ = True
    match _ [] = False
    match ([x]:t) ([y]:s) | x==y = match t s
    match q       (_:s)          = match q s                           == 

not.null $ [()|r<-sequence [ [[y],[]] | y<-ys], match [[x]|x<-xs] r]   ==

match2 xs ys
  where
    match2 [] _ = True
    match2 _ [] = False
    match2 (x:t) (y:s) | x==y = match2 t s
    match2 q     (_:s)        = match2 q s
```

Comment: The first option here is an AWFUL algorithm. It takes exponential time to determine if the empty string is a subsequence of any other.

Comment: ..and a truly lovely concept - what a way to find all subsequences! Mmmmmm.

Comment: @AndrewC I guess it's true what "the evolution of Haskell programmer" says about "liberat[ing] one[self] from petty concerns about, e.g., ... efficiency " ... :) :) :). And I wonder, can this `filterM` code be re-written/compiled for a linear time execution, exploiting laziness?... I think it sure can be *hand*-re-written for this, fusing `(==)` (from `elem`) and `sequence`! (of course the 2nd code is such a rewrite). I wonder what would it take for a *compiler* to be able to achieve this... (all this talking without testing! maybe GHC is already that smart?...)

Comment: @AndrewC I hold the unpopular view that Haskell had not avoided success for long enough -- did not deliver on the original promise of equational reasoning, where the 1st code in this answer could be *legitimately* seen as *equivalent* to the 2nd and we could expect to get away with writing such high-level specifications always and let the compiler figure out efficient re-writes for them! This of course is conventionally considered to be a *"''sufficiently smart compiler'' **fallacy**"*...

Comment: @BenMillwood ... using `filterM (\x-> [False,True])` would indeed be far better in that regard. :)

Comment: @WillNess: that takes exponential time to determine if any string is a subsequence of itself (and I think the general case is exponential either way). The quadratic algorithm does, I think, use a genuinely different idea, so you have to have quite a creative compiler to come up with it...

Comment: @BenMillwood I think it's the same idea, in general - either demand a match on a character or allow it to be skipped - that's why I used that order initially, `[True,False]`. (Plus, the first argument should be fully consumed in the end.) Well, the 2nd code is more forcing, if the match is possible it doesn't allow for a skip unlike the first code, yes... but I was more thinking of the 1st code as not *code* but *specification*, with `elem` fused into `sequence`... (the creative optimization here is, we scan only once - no restarts)  And I think 2nd code is *linear* in its 2nd arg's length.

Comment: @BenMillwood about my reference to "sequence": I was thinking of this possible implementation of `filterM p xs = liftM concat $ sequence $ [ do {t<-p x; return [x|t]} | x<-xs]`.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone just looking for a simple linear-time implementation, here's one.

```
subseq :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
[]     `subseq` _      = True
(_:_ ) `subseq` []     = False
(a:as) `subseq` (b:bs) = (if a == b then as else a:as) `subseq` bs
```